# Uwamp Online Mode

Tags: uwamp

I have set UWAMP to online mode but I was unable to access with ip address with other devices which share the same wifi connection.

[image]

Can someone help me?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#UWAMP Generate Virtual Host
    DocumentRoot "{DOCUMENTPATH}/"
    ServerName "main-serveur"
    Alias "/mysql/" "{PHPAPPS}/phpmyadmin/"
    Alias "/mysql" "{PHPAPPS}/phpmyadmin/"
    Alias "/uwamp/" "{PHPAPPS}/uwamp/"
    Alias "/uwamp" "{PHPAPPS}/uwamp/"
    <Directory "{PHPAPPS}/phpmyadmin/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "{PHPAPPS}/uwamp/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "{DOCUMENTPATH}/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
        {ONLINE_MODE}       
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried, not working

Comment: All of them? Then update your question with your current config and the error message

Comment: @Martheen Updated

Comment: What is the error message? What is your firewall config?

Comment: It shows " 'Apache HTTP Server' is already in the list of exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the httpd.exe is in the exception list so I just tick it and now working properly.